# word/phrase for initial set of data or givens

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm searching for a neutral phrase that conveys the concept of the initial condition/situation/position/set of givens or factors impacting an outcome. For example, the idea of a 'headstart' conveys an advantageous initial position toward pursuing a goal. I am searching for something similar without the connotation of an advantage - but simply indicating the 'start' position, and a certain 'opening' configuration of facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***[Mise en scène](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mise+en+scene)***
- ***Situation*** or ***composition*** (the initial setup of a [chess problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_problem))
- ***[Form](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/form)***, to which is applied a ***[handicap](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handicap)***

Comment: The sports or competitive analogy is apropo. I can't use the notion of 'odds' - because I'm not describing probabilities, but if there were a word for the sum of the abilities of a sports team - (individual averages, the team's prior successes etc.) as considered before the match begins - that would work as a good metaphor

Comment: @llana - A *handicap* is what judges (in horse racing, bowling, golf, etc.) apply to the situation you're describing in order to even the playing field.  So that's where I'm searching - what do handicappers call the situation **before** they apply a handicap?

Comment: @llana - I just remembered the word: **form**.  The [Daily Racing Form](http://www.drf.com/) is a paper dedicated to all aspects of racing, but in general terms "form" refers to a horse's record PLUS his race-day condition, while **the form** refers to the condition of all entrants in a race: "What's the form?"  It has also come to be used conversationally: "You're in fine form today, aren't you?"

Comment: I think I may just use 'handicap' for the context I need - Thanks!!

Comment: @llana - Fair enough, but be aware that your readers may take away a different meaning than you intend.  A handicap is a penalty added to the stronger competitor - in horse racing, faster horses must carry extra weight - or (as in golf) subtracted from the score of a weaker competitor.  It is *not* the initial position - that's the form.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> Original

As in the original condition, or situation, position